# How to delete file from the server using plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to delete a file from the server using plpgsql.

First I `lo_import` and `lo_get` the contents of the file, perform some updates/inserts, then `lo_export` the file to another folder.

Now what i would like to do after successful `lo_export` is to remove the original file.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your user role has `pg_write_server_files` permission, you can do `COPY (select '') TO '/tmp/yourfilename'`, which deletes your file **contents** and creates a new text file with a single empty line at its place.

If your user role has `pg_execute_server_program`, you can run `COPY (select '') TO PROGRAM 'rm -f /tmp/yourfilename'` and your file will be gone.

Of course everything here must be carried on with great diligence. I assume if your user role has one of these permissions, then you are skilled enough to take all precautions.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL doesn't allow to manipulate with files native way. This is task for application server. The workaround can be done with some external procedures - stored procedures (functions) written in PLPerlu or PLPythonu (untrusted) language.

Answer (score 0):

pl/pgSQL is a trusted language. That means that no access to files, the operating system or any network functionality is possible.

As Pavel pointed out, you must use an untrusted language. However functions in any untrusted language must be created by a superuser, no regular user can do that.